# Git two origins in which pull from one and push to another

Tags: git, github

I have two origins in my git local one is original(A) from where I Had cloned code and other is my own repository(B).
I have to push to B changes from A + my local changes.
What are the commands so that this happens smoothly.
Please explain how will your commands work in context of HEAD and commits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's important to note that `origin` is just the default name for most remote repositories, they can be called anything. In this example we will use `originA` and `originB`, and assume all work is done in `master` for the sake of simplicity.

To set up a new remote repository:

```
git remote add originA https://github.com/user/repositoryName.git
```

To change the URL of an existing repository, replace `add` with `set-url` in the previous command.

To fetch all the commits from `originA` and merge them into the local `master` branch run:

```
git pull originA master
```

If there are no merge conflicts, `originA/master` and local `master` will be the same and HEAD will be set to the most recent commit.

Then set up `originB` as described above (if not already set up) and make any local commits, which can be pushed by running:

```
git push originB master
```

This assumes your local repo has all the commits `originB` does, the push will be blocked if not. The only way to push code directly between `originA` and `originB` would be to log in to one of those servers, otherwise the code has to be bounced between your local repository.

Comment: i had added comments but now i dont know where they are gone